# maven jacoco plugin reports always show 0% of coverage

Tags: maven, testing, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

JaCoCo reports always shows 0% of coverage but Intellij integrated report is ok. I already see others StackOverflow questions but none helped. Below is my jacoco-plugin and surefire-plugin snnipet from pom.xml configuration:

**EDIT:**

```xml
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <runOrder>balanced</runOrder>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

My last attempts were order **surefire** and **jacoco-plugin** but it doesn't work. There is any relation with surefire and jacoco-plugin?

Comment: Full pom file, JDK Version?, Why configuring destFile etc. ? Best would be an example project on Github or alike?

Comment: I can't show the full pom file. But JDK version is 1.8. I changed the plugin configuration and I'm going to update the question ok?

Comment: Remove the junit provider dependency from surefire not needed. Have you added a dependency to JUnit 4.X? Do you use JUnit 4.X ? Or do you use JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5 ?) ...

Comment: I'm using Junit 4.X

Comment: The problem persists after remove surefire junit dependency

Comment: Full pom file is really helpful or make a simple example project on github or alike as I mentioned before....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225785/discussion-between-abilio-castro-and-khmarbaise).

Comment: You are missing the `report` goal in your `pom.xml`. Did you try adding that?

Comment: I solved it a long time ago, but seeing the code now I viewed that I added among other things the `report` goal in `jacoco-maven-plugin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it a long time ago, but seeing the code now I viewed that I added among other things the `report` goal in `jacoco-maven-plugin`